# Dividir argumentos com regex

Tags: php, regex

Eu tenho dificuldades com regex. Preciso apenas dividir uma string de entradas.

```
Input: "arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4"; Output: [arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4]

Input: "arg1 'arg 2' arg3 arg4"; Output: [arg1, arg 2, arg3, arg4]
```

Meu problema está no segundo exemplo. Pois quando o argumento está entre aspas, preciso mante-lo integro. E como estou usando a função explode do PHP, acabo tendo dois argumentos (`[arg, 2]`);

Comment: É php via linha de comando?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supondo que o padrão seja `arg` sendo fixo :

```
$str = "arg1 'arg 2' arg3 arg4";
preg_match_all("~arg\d|'arg[^']+'~", $str, $matchs);

print_r($matchs[0]);
```

Caso não queira incluir as `'` use : `arg\d|(?<=')arg[^']+(?=')`

#### Edição

Como comentado `arg` na verdade são argumentos de qualquer tipo:

Assim a regex teve se ser alterada :

Input : `seed.php app:init "app" "/seed/" "Lucas Mahle"`
Regex : `['"].*?['"]|[^ ]+`

Comment: Não é fixo. Como ficaria? Um exemplo do input: 'seed.php app:init "app" "/seed/" "Lucas Mahle'

Comment: @lucasDotCom esse tipo de coisa deve ser especificado quando se fala de regex. So para saber você pode abrir com aspa simples e fechar  com dupla e vise versa?

Comment: @lucasDotCom Editei, veja se agora esta de acordo.

Comment: Guilherme, funcionou perfeitamente. Era apenas isso que eu precisava.

Answer (score 1):

Não tenho conhecimento em PHP, mas criei um exemplo em javascript que talvez possa lhe ajudar a compreender a expressão regular (acompanhe os comentários no código):

```js
function splitArguments(arguments) {
  return arguments.replace(
      /* procura tudo que está entre ' nos argumentos */
      /\'([^']+)\'/g, function(replacement) {
        /* procura espaço no que está entre ' e substitui por '__' */
        return replacement.replace(/ /g, '__');
      })
    // troca os espaços em branco dos separadores por ||
    .replace(/ /g, '||')
    // retorna o __ para espaço em branco dentro do argumento
    .replace(/__/g, ' ')
    // aplica split pelo novo separador de argumentos ||
    .split(/\|\|/g);
}

console.log(splitArguments("arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4"));
console.log(splitArguments("arg1 'arg 2' arg3 arg4"));
console.log(splitArguments("arg1 'arg 2' arg3 'arg 4'"));
```

> Acredito que está atualização resolveu as falhas, se observar alguma falha em algum caso de teste comente.

Comment: Obrigado Fernando, seu código me serviu para outro problema.